# SSRS 2012 Report Builder fails to run from remote host - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS 2012 native mode. I can run Report Builder from localhost where SSRS is installed.
I am unable to run Report Builder from other machines, and I am getting such error:

> Downloading http//10.149.100.*/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application did not succeed.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Here is my scenario:
SSRS is installed on a server which is in a workgroup. There is local user on that server, ie. ruser.
I am accessing report manager from other computer which is in other workgroup/domain using address http//ssrs_server/Reports and I am passing ruser login and password. I can run every report in such way.
But I can't run Report Builder using button in the report manager.

I already tried this instruction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8faf2938-b71b-4e61-a172-46da2209ff55%28v=sql.110%29
and I set Basic Authentication with anonymous access to report builder.
Specifically I performed all steps from 1 to 6 in the section  Enabling Anonymous Access to Report Builder Application Files.
The only result was that after I clicked on Report Builder button I received HTTP 500 error instead of HTTP 401.

Then I found out that I can place Report Builder installation files on the IIS and set custom url to the Report Builder. I did it and I could finally run report builder from other machine.

The only problem is that when the Report Builder is run from custom IIS URL then it doesn't connect to report server automatically.
However it is connecting automatically when it is run from default SSRS link.

What I want to achieve is:

- either make the Report Builder to be runnable from default SSRS link
- either make the Report Builder to be runnable from a custom IIS link (already did it) but also make it automatically connecting to report server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
The first step is to enable Basic Authentication using this instruction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8faf2938-b71b-4e61-a172-46da2209ff55%28v=sql.110%29

But I omitted step 4.

Next I used this instruction: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/955809?wa=wsignin1.0
and performed Method 3 - Create an explicit Web.config file

The web.config file need to be saved at this location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.ATC\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.ATC\Reporting Services\RSTempFiles\"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: nice solution by Basic Authentication  : )

Answer (score 0):

Because ReportingService is use Windows Authentication .

so you can't use IP Address to link your ReportServer.

i will suggestion use Active Directory Environment in ReportingService.

if you use a normal workgroup. you can try this

1.modify hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc .

map hostnames to IP . Like: win-4mheefkokk4 192.168.179.5

2.change your ReportBuilder URL 
From 
http: //192.168.179.5/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application 
To 
http:// win-4mheefkokk4/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application

Then you can install ReportBuilder by ClickOnce mode. Hope it's can help you :)

Comment: It didn't worked. Error message: + Downloading http://rtics-atc1/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application did not succeed.
  + The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: @scar80 your user account need a execute ReportBuilder privilege . try use administrator account . btw if you use Basic Authentication , user account & password will use Plain text transport

Comment: Awesome! Just using a domain instead of an IP did the job for me!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to SSRS 2012 - step by step IoI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/cc281309(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

1 - Verify the report server is configured for Basic authentication by checking the authentication settings in the RSReportServer.config file, below the example:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsBasic>
            <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
            <Realm></Realm>
            <DefaultDomain></DefaultDomain>
        </RSWindowsBasic>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

2 - Create a BIN folder under the ReportBuilder folder. By default, this folder is located at \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder.

3 - Copy the following assemblies from the ReportServer\Bin (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin) folder
to the ReportBuilder\BIN (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\ReportingServices\ReportServer\ReportBuilder\bin) folder:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.dll

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll

> ReportingServicesAppDomainManager.dll

> RSHttpRuntime.dll

4- create a Web.config file to process Report Builder requests under an Anonymous account:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder\Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />  
<identity impersonate="true "/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Authentication mode must be set to Windows if you include a Web.config file.

Identity impersonate can be True or False.

Set it to False if you do not want ASP.NET to read the security token. The request will run in the security context of the Report Server service.

Set it to True if you want ASP.NET to read the security token from the host layer. If you set it to True, you must also specify userName and password to designate an Anonymous account. The credentials you specify will determine the security context under which the request is issued.

5 - Save the Web.config file to the ReportBuilder\bin folder.

6 - Open RSReportServer.config file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config), in the Services section, find IsReportManagerEnabled and add the following setting below it:

```
<IsReportManagerEnabled>True</IsReportManagerEnabled>
    <IsReportBuilderAnonymousAccessEnabled>True</IsReportBuilderAnonymousAccessEnabled>
```

7 - Save RSReportServer.config and close the file.

8 - Restart the report server.